# Clojure: Chaining group-by :key with select-keys on remaining keys

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to understand a simple (as in other languages) workflow with clojure maps.

**It basically comes down to this: How can chain these operations?**

1. `group-by` :key on a vector of maps
2. `select-keys` on remaining maps without the previous key
3. `group-by` again (0..n times) and select-keys
4. `count` unique key instances at the end.

See also my previous question: [Aggregate and Count in Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139680/clojure-aggregate-and-count-in-maps)

**Example:**

Given a vector of maps

```
(def DATA [{:a "X", :b "M", :c "K", :d 10}
           {:a "Y", :b "M", :c "K", :d 20}
           {:a "Y", :b "M", :c "F", :d 30}
           {:a "Y", :b "P", :c "G", :d 40}])
```

performing `group-by`

```
(defn get-tree-level-1 [] (group-by :a DATA))
```

yields a map grouped by the value of that particular key.

```
{ X [{:a X, :b M, :c K, :d 10}],
  Y [{:a Y, :b M, :c K, :d 20}
     {:a Y, :b M, :c F, :d 30}
     {:a Y, :b P, :c G, :d 40}]}
```

So far, so good. But what if I want to build a **tree-like structure** out of the data, which means selecting the remaining keys and ignoring some, select `:b` and `:c` and ignore `:d`, which would yield in the next level:

```
(def DATA2   [{ :X [{:b "M", :c "K"}],
                :Y [{:b "M", :c "K"}
                    {:b "M", :c "F"}
                    {:b "P", :c "G"}]}])
```

And finally, counting all instances of the remaining keys (e.g. count all unique values of the `:b` key under the `Y`-root):

```
(def DATA3   [{ :X [{:M  1}],
                :Y [{:M  2}
                    {:P  1}])
```

I tried doing a `select-keys` after the `group-by`, but the result was empty after the first step:

```
(defn get-proc-sums []
  (into {}
    (map
      (fn [ [k vs] ]
        [k (select-keys vs [:b :c])])
      (group-by :a DATA))))
```

Comment: This is really similar to another question of yours. I'm not completely sure that the approach(es) you are taking is the correct one. It seems that nesting your data initially is making your later steps more difficult, rather than just more detailed filtering on a flatish list of maps.

Comment: I'm also not sure whether this is right. The reasoning behind the nested structure is: Given a large set of data, I'd like to build a look-up tree where I can group together equal key/value pairs and based on which keys are chosen as "uniqueness" identifiers, can count all the remaining instances. I'm not sure if there is a way of filtering out the wanted result out of the original set in a better fashion. I just try to emulate the result I want with what I would try to get out with other languages.

Comment: I think an example with data closer to the real application might help. For instance I'm not seeing any logical reason for the discussion about the :d key being present at all, and you don't seem to really gain much by having DATA3 defined versus having a function that could count instances where :a was "X" and :b was "M". Maybe try to rephrase as more of a blackbox, starting with DATA as is and then only what you want to do with it next.

Comment: You're right in that I should be more precise with the problem statement. I tried to keep it as general as possible so as to get to a more flexible solution that I can understand and extend easily depending on the underlying data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Repeated application of group-by is the wrong tool: it doesn't compose with itself very well. Rather, go over your input maps and transform each of them, once, into a format that's useful to you (using `for` or `map`), and then reduce over that to build your tree structure. Here is a simple implementation:

```
(defn hierarchy [keyseq xs]
  (reduce (fn [m [ks x]]
            (update-in m ks conj x))
          {}
          (for [x xs]
            [(map x keyseq) (apply dissoc x keyseq)])))

user> (hierarchy [:a :b :c] '[{:a "X", :b "M", :c "K", :d 10}
                              {:a "Y", :b "M", :c "K", :d 20}
                              {:a "Y", :b "M", :c "F", :d 30}
                              {:a "Y", :b "P", :c "G", :d 40}])
{"Y" {"P" {"G" ({:d 40})},
      "M" {"F" ({:d 30}),
           "K" ({:d 20})}},
 "X" {"M" {"K" ({:d 10})}}}
```

This gives you the hierarchical format that you want, with a list of all maps with only the "leftover" keys. From this, you can count them, distinct them, remove the `:d` key, or whatever else you want, either by writing another function that processes this map, or by adjusting what happens in the reduce function, or the `for` comprehension, above.

Comment: This is the great generic answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

the mistake is that you are trying to select keys from values collection, while you should do it for every item in coll, e.g. using `map`:

```
(defn get-proc-sums []
  (into {}
        (map
         (fn [ [k vs] ]
           [k (map #(select-keys % [:b :c]) vs)])
         (group-by :a DATA))))

user> (get-proc-sums)
{"X" ({:b "M", :c "K"}), 
 "Y" ({:b "M", :c "K"} {:b "M", :c "F"} {:b "P", :c "G"})}
```

what you're doing is:

```
user> (group-by :a DATA)
{"X" [{:a "X", :b "M", :c "K", :d 10}], 
 "Y" [{:a "Y", :b "M", :c "K", :d 20} 
      {:a "Y", :b "M", :c "F", :d 30} 
      {:a "Y", :b "P", :c "G", :d 40}]}
```

then you are processing every key-value pair (let's take "Y" pair for that):

```
user> (let [[k vals] ["Y" ((group-by :a DATA) "Y")]]
         [k vals])
["Y" [{:a "Y", :b "M", :c "K", :d 20} 
      {:a "Y", :b "M", :c "F", :d 30} 
      {:a "Y", :b "P", :c "G", :d 40}]]
```

so you do `select-keys` for a vector of maps:

```
user> (select-keys [{:a "Y", :b "M", :c "K", :d 20} 
                    {:a "Y", :b "M", :c "F", :d 30} 
                    {:a "Y", :b "P", :c "G", :d 40}]
                   [:a :b])
{}
```

which is logical, since you don't have these keys in vector.

```
user> (map #(select-keys % [:a :b]) [{:a "Y", :b "M", :c "K", :d 20} 
                                     {:a "Y", :b "M", :c "F", :d 30} 
                                     {:a "Y", :b "P", :c "G", :d 40}])
({:a "Y", :b "M"} {:a "Y", :b "M"} {:a "Y", :b "P"})
```

**update:** to fulfill the whole task, I would propose the following:

```
(defn process-data [data]
  (->> data
       (group-by :a)
       (map (fn [[k vals]] [k (frequencies (map :b vals))]))
       (into {})))

user> (process-data DATA)
{"X" {"M" 1}, "Y" {"M" 2, "P" 1}}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, understood `[k (map #(select-keys % [:b :c]) vs)]`. Do you have advice on how to properly continue chaining more methods for each element after applying select-keys,  `order-by` and `fn` for instance?

Answer (score 1):

Here I'll only be addressing the workflow aspect of your question, and one way of thinking through the function design. I present only one way out of many, but I think this way is sufficiently idiomatic. If you're looking for an implementation, [amalloy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36186526/2472391) provided a fine one.

The problem you pose is a perfect use-case for recursion. You want to build a nested structure where each level of nesting (except for the last) just follows the same grouping process on the previous grouping result. The last level of nesting instead performs a count. And you don't know in advance how many levels of nesting there will be.

You're throwing away the `:c` and the `:d`, so you might as well do that at the start -- it's logically a distinct processing step.

Let's assume you've written your function (call it `foo` -- I leave its writing as an exercises for the reader). **It can construct the nested structure in terms of recursive calls to itself.**

Let's take your example data set:

```
(def DATA [{:a "X", :b "M", :c "K", :d 10}
           {:a "Y", :b "M", :c "K", :d 20}
           {:a "Y", :b "M", :c "F", :d 30}
           {:a "Y", :b "P", :c "G", :d 40}])
```

Let's ignore `:d`, so our pre-processed set looks like:

```
(def filtered-data [{:a "X", :b "M", :c "K"}
                    {:a "Y", :b "M", :c "K"}
                    {:a "Y", :b "M", :c "F"}
                    {:a "Y", :b "P", :c "G"}])
```

**Example**

And here's an example "query":

```
(foo filtered-data
     [:a :b :c])
```

We want it to spit out a nested structure that looks a bit like this:

```
[{ :X (foo [{:b "M", :c "K"}]
           [:b :c]),
   :Y (foo [{:b "M", :c "K"}
            {:b "M", :c "F"}
            {:b "P", :c "G"}]
           [:b :c]}])
```

This in turn is equivalent to:

```
[{ :X [{:M (foo [{:c "K"}]
                [:c])}],
   :Y [{:M (foo [{:c "K"}
                 {:c "F"}]
                [:c]),
        :P (foo [{:c "G"}]
                [:c])}]
]}
```

These `foo`s can easily recognize the end of the recursion and switch to a counting behavior:

```
[{ :X [{:M [{:K 1}]}],
   :Y [{:M [{:F 1}
            {:K 1}],
        :P [{:G 1}]
      }]
]}
```

Personally, if I were building up such a structure, I'd target one with less "superfluous" nesting, such as this [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie):

```
{"X" {"M" {"K" 1}},
 "Y" {"M" {"F" 1, "K" 1},
      "P" {"G" 1}}
```

But I don't know your use case and whether these are truly superfluous. And if you might want to use this data to produce more than one statistic, then see how [amalloy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36186526/2472391) made a [condensed structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) from which you could derive counts, or anything else.

Comment: The superfluous nesting is indeed unnecessary. I was indeed going for a trie. That was the least of my problems, however, as I was trying to wrap my head around the recursion approach that you broke down rather meticulously. (Thank you for that.)